# How to instantiate a derived class object in Java?

Tags: java

In this code

```
class Foo {

    public int a = 3;
}

class Bar extends Foo {

    public int a = 8;
}

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Bar();
        Bar f = new Bar();
    }
}
```

What is the difference between

```
Foo f = new Bar();
```

**and**

```
Bar f = new Bar();
```

Thank You

Comment: The first instantiation is more broad than the second.  A `Bar` is a `Foo`, but a `Foo` may not be a `Bar`.

Comment: Hint: this is very basic stuff. Please do some prior research on such topics **in advance**. Stackoverflow is not programming school where you turn to to be **teached** stuff that is documented all over the place.

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner. Please do provide me the link to the reading material for this topic. Thank You. @Jägermeister

Comment: @Jägermeister you are correct, but do not forget that we all begun from somewhere...

Comment: You can start with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming) and take a look this picture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Multilevel_Inheritance.jpg . I do agree with the comments from @Jägermeister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relationship is called the is-a relationship. Every `Bar` object is a `Foo` object. However, a `Foo` object cannot be a `Bar` object.

When you call `Foo f = new Bar()`, You are creating a `Foo` object, which means that only the fields of Foo are accessible in f. That is, `f.a` in this case is 3.

On the other hand, `Bar f = new Bar()` creates a `Bar` object, which means that `f.a` will give you 8 in this case.

Comment: hint: lookup concept of substitutability online